# libgdx rotate 3d object following mouse

Tags: java, libgdx

i try to rotate a 3D instance when I move the mouse. i use Orthographic Camera, and i have a tiled isomap in background.

[EDIT] I use this code :

```
public boolean mouseMoved (int x, int y) {
    Vector3 direction = new Vector3();
    Vector3 worldCoordinate = cam.unproject(new Vector3(x, y, 0));

    direction = (worldCoordinate).sub(position).nor();
    direction.set(-direction.x, -direction.y, -direction.z);

    Matrix4 instanceRotation = instance.transform.cpy().mul(instance.transform);

    instanceRotation.setToLookAt(direction, new Vector3(0,-1,0));
    instanceRotation.rotate(0, 0, 1, 180);
    quat = new Quaternion();
    instanceRotation.getRotation(quat);

    instance.transform.set(position, quat);

    return false;
}
```

Now, the instance follows the cursor, but in all axes. I just want to turn on the Y axis. I can change quat.x = 0 and quat.z = 0 to lock the rotation. After that, the rotation only works on the Y axis. But, the model should turn over if my cursor is at the top of the screen, but it remains facing, no matter where my cursor is.

I don't know how to convert the coordinates to tell my rotation that it needs to turn over. And to modify the quat in this way is not very elegant

Edit : Some image for illustrate what i want

Here, with cursor in the bottom of the screen, the model turn to look in good direction : [image: Working]

Here, the model dont turn over, like the cursor is in bottom of the screen : [image: Not working]